# Flutter - Provider - Add Map to List Replacing

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, provider

Here I need to create a list of maps.

I'm using `provider` to keep data.

But when I commanded to `list.add()` it also replacing the 1st element.

Here's my code.

I'm fetching data from firestore collection.

**add_inv_stream.dart**

```
class AddInvStream extends StatelessWidget {
  const AddInvStream({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FirebaseServices services = FirebaseServices();
    final provider = Provider.of<InventoryProvider>(context);

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: services.inventory
          .where('fishType', isEqualTo: provider.inventoryData['fishType'])
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Center(child: Text('Something wrong!'));
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }

        if (snapshot.data!.size == 0) {
          return const Center(
            child: Text('No inventories'),
          );
        }

        return AddInvData(snapshot: snapshot, services: services);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**add_inv_data.dart**

```
class AddInvData extends StatefulWidget {
  final AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> snapshot;
  final FirebaseServices services;

  const AddInvData({Key? key, required this.snapshot, required this.services})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddInvData> createState() => _AddInvDataState();
}

class _AddInvDataState extends State<AddInvData> {      
  List abc = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final providerr = Provider.of<InventoryProvider>(context);

    return ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: widget.snapshot.data!.size,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        Map<String, dynamic> sellerData =
            widget.snapshot.data!.docs[index].data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

        return InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            print('Date: ${sellerData['date']} | QTY: ${sellerData['qty']}');
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return Dialog(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                  ),
                  elevation: 16,
                  child: Form(
                    key: _formkey,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            providerr.getInvSellerData(
                              sellerDate1: sellerData['date'],
                              sellerQty1: sellerData['qty'],
                            );
                          });
                          print(providerr.inventorySellerData);
                          abc.add(providerr.inventorySellerData);
                          print(abc);
                        },
                        child: const Text('ASSIGN'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 30),
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(sellerData['date']),
                  Text('${sellerData['qty']} kg'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**inv_provider.dart**

```
class InventoryProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, dynamic> inventorySellerData = {};

  getInvSellerData({
    String? sellerDate1,
    String? sellerQty1,
  }) {
    if (sellerDate1 != null) {
      inventorySellerData['sellerDate1'] = sellerDate1;
    }

    if (sellerQty1 != null) {
      inventorySellerData['sellerQty1'] = sellerQty1;
    }

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

There are only two collections I have created and when I tapped on first container it's printing
**Date: 10/31/2022 | QTY: 50**
and a dialog is showing.

Then I clicked assign button it's printing
**{sellerDate1: 10/31/2022, sellerQty1: 50}

[{sellerDate1: 10/31/2022, sellerQty1: 50}]**

After that I clicked on second container it's printing
**Date: 11/25/2022 | QTY: 54**
and a dialog is showing same as first container.

Then I clicked assign button it's printing
**{sellerDate1: 11/25/2022, sellerQty1: 54}

[{sellerDate1: 11/25/2022, sellerQty1: 54}, {sellerDate1: 11/25/2022, sellerQty1: 54}]**

---

I need to get printed when clicked assign button
**[{sellerDate1: 10/31/2022, sellerQty1: 50}, {sellerDate1: 11/25/2022, sellerQty1: 54}]**

How can I do that?

Why is this replacing all the elements in the list?

Answer (score 1):

How about add map to list `abc` outside of dialog.

```
  onTap: () {
            print('Date: ${sellerData['date']} | QTY: ${sellerData['qty']}');
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return Dialog(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                  ),
                  elevation: 16,
                  child: Form(
                    key: _formkey,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                        // no need call setState. because you already update state by provider
                            providerr.getInvSellerData(
                              sellerDate1: sellerData['date'],
                              sellerQty1: sellerData['qty'],
                            );
                          print(providerr.inventorySellerData);

                        },
                        child: const Text('ASSIGN'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
           // add here
            abc.add(providerr.inventorySellerData);
            print(abc);
          },
```

Comment: No that's not the problem. I created an empty list and added data to that list. Then I added them to provider it's working fine. Thank you btw.